# Unused Buildings in Rise of Nations

Tags: rise-of-nations

In Rise of Nations: Gold there is a couple of buildings that aren't in any of the Rise of Nations campaigns or maps. Specifically "El Dorado" and "Statue of Lenin". I read on a forum that there was a scenario that used these buildings but was either scrapped or wasn't completed in time for release.

Is there any tutorial or scenario that uses some of these special buildings? If so where are they located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The El Dorado building is meant for the new world campaign which is available in the extended edition and should be in the gold edition (since it should include the original plus extended edition). It is meant to give a metal in a map with few mountains. The battle that contains El Dorado is the invasion of the territory located in the north west of South America where Venezuela is located.

The Statue of Lenin serves no purpose but is present in some cold war maps as decoration near Russian cities. I've heard you can make custom scenarios with such buildings.